# Is there a way to label a region with its corresponding continent? Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have been given a csv with a number of regions and countries. My objective is to create a new column with the corresponding continent for each country/region. I created arrays for each continent that lists all of the countries within it. However, this approach leaves the regions and cities unaccounted for. Is there a better way to approach this? None of the mapping information I have found in my research corresponds to continents. Below is my current/inefficient approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psycopg2 as ps

#Part 1
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurenaxon/ding_INFO5502_SPRING2020/master/indicator%20hiv%20estimated%20prevalence%25%2015-49.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

Africa = ('Algeria','Angola','Benin','Botswana','Burkina','Burundi','Cameroon','Cape Verde','Central African Republic','Chad','Comoros','Congo','Congo, Democratic Republic of','Djibouti','Egypt','Equatorial Guinea','Eritrea','Ethiopia','Gabon','Gambia','Ghana','Guinea','Guinea-Bissau','Ivory Coast','Kenya','Lesotho','Liberia','Libya','Madagascar','Malawi','Mali','Mauritania','Mauritius','Morocco','Mozambique','Namibia','Niger','Nigeria','Rwanda','Sao Tome and Principe','Senegal','Seychelles','Sierra Leone','Somalia','South Africa','South Sudan','Sudan','Swaziland','Tanzania','Togo','Tunisia','Uganda','Zambia','Zimbabwe')
Asia = ('Afghanistan','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Bhutan','Brunei','Burma (Myanmar)','Cambodia','China','East Timor','India','Indonesia','Iran','Iraq','Israel','Japan','Jordan','Kazakhstan','Korea, North','Korea, South','Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan','Laos','Lebanon','Malaysia','Maldives','Mongolia','Nepal','Oman','Pakistan','Philippines','Qatar','Russian Federation','Saudi Arabia','Singapore','Sri Lanka','Syria','Tajikistan','Thailand','Turkey','Turkmenistan','United Arab Emirates','Uzbekistan','Vietnam','Yemen')
Europe = ('Albania','Andorra','Armenia','Austria','Azerbaijan','Belarus','Belgium','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Denmark','Estonia','Finland','France','Georgia','Germany','Greece','Hungary','Iceland','Ireland','Italy','Latvia','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macedonia','Malta','Moldova','Monaco','Montenegro','Netherlands','Norway','Poland','Portugal','Romania','San Marino','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Ukraine','United Kingdom','Vatican City')
North_America = ('Antigua and Barbuda','Bahamas','Barbados','Belize','Canada','Costa Rica','Cuba','Dominica','Dominican Republic','El Salvador','Grenada','Guatemala','Haiti','Honduras','Jamaica','Mexico','Nicaragua','Panama','Saint Kitts and Nevis','Saint Lucia','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Trinidad and Tobago','United States')
South_America = ('Argentina','Bolivia','Brazil','Chile','Colombia','Ecuador','Guyana','Paraguay','Peru','Suriname','Uruguay','Venezuela')
Australia_Oceania = ('Australia','Fiji','Kiribati','Marshall Islands','Micronesia','Nauru','New Zealand','Palau','Papua New Guinea','Samoa','Solomon Islands','Tonga','Tuvalu','Vanuatu')

country = df["Estimated HIV Prevalence% - (Ages 15-49)"]

def GetConti(country):
    if country in Africa:
        return "Africa"
    elif country in Asia:
        return "Asia"
    elif country in Europe:
        return "Europe"
    elif country in North_America:
        return "North America"
    elif country in South_America:
        return "South America"
    elif country in Australia_Oceania:
        return "Australia/Oceania"
    else:
        return "Other"



df['Continent']=country.apply(GetConti)
df.to_csv('url', sep='\t')


print(df)
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer your question, but you should use a Python [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a tuple. It will lookup in O(1) instead of O(n) using a tuple or list.

Answer (score 1):

To run this operation in **O(1)** time you would need a hash table (dictionary) where each country is a key that corresponds to it continent, which would look like this:

```
{
    'Algeria': 'Africa',
    'Angola': 'Africa',
    ...

    'Afghanistan': 'Asia',
    ...
}
```

This, of course, is quite tedious to write, so you can convert the data you have to this format with the following:

```
class continents:
    Africa = ('Algeria','Angola','Benin','Botswana','Burkina','Burundi','Cameroon','Cape Verde','Central African Republic','Chad','Comoros','Congo','Congo, Democratic Republic of','Djibouti','Egypt','Equatorial Guinea','Eritrea','Ethiopia','Gabon','Gambia','Ghana','Guinea','Guinea-Bissau','Ivory Coast','Kenya','Lesotho','Liberia','Libya','Madagascar','Malawi','Mali','Mauritania','Mauritius','Morocco','Mozambique','Namibia','Niger','Nigeria','Rwanda','Sao Tome and Principe', 'Senegal','Seychelles','Sierra Leone','Somalia','South Africa','South Sudan','Sudan','Swaziland','Tanzania','Togo','Tunisia','Uganda','Zambia','Zimbabwe')

    Asia = ('Afghanistan','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Bhutan','Brunei','Burma (Myanmar)','Cambodia','China','East Timor','India','Indonesia','Iran','Iraq','Israel','Japan','Jordan','Kazakhstan','Korea, North','Korea, South','Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan','Laos','Lebanon','Malaysia','Maldives','Mongolia','Nepal','Oman','Pakistan','Philippines','Qatar','Russian Federation','Saudi Arabia','Singapore','Sri Lanka','Syria','Tajikistan','Thailand','Turkey','Turkmenistan','United Arab Emirates','Uzbekistan','Vietnam','Yemen')

    Europe = ('Albania','Andorra','Armenia','Austria','Azerbaijan','Belarus','Belgium','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Denmark','Estonia','Finland','France','Georgia','Germany','Greece','Hungary','Iceland','Ireland','Italy','Latvia','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macedonia','Malta','Moldova','Monaco','Montenegro','Netherlands','Norway','Poland','Portugal','Romania','San Marino','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Ukraine','United Kingdom','Vatican City')

    North_America = ('Antigua and Barbuda','Bahamas','Barbados','Belize','Canada','Costa Rica','Cuba','Dominica','Dominican Republic','El Salvador','Grenada','Guatemala','Haiti','Honduras','Jamaica','Mexico','Nicaragua','Panama','Saint Kitts and Nevis','Saint Lucia','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Trinidad and Tobago','United States')
    South_America = ('Argentina','Bolivia','Brazil','Chile','Colombia','Ecuador','Guyana','Paraguay','Peru','Suriname','Uruguay','Venezuela')
    Australia_Oceania = ('Australia','Fiji','Kiribati','Marshall Islands','Micronesia','Nauru','New Zealand','Palau','Papua New Guinea','Samoa','Solomon Islands','Tonga','Tuvalu','Vanuatu')

country_to_continent_map = {}
for name in dir(continents):
    if name.startswith('_'): continue

    country_set = getattr(continents, name)

    for country in country_set:
        country_to_continent_map[country] = name
```

Then write it to a file somewhere:

```
file = f'''
country_to_continent_map = {str(country_to_continent_map)}
'''
with open('some_file.py', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(file)
```

Now you can simply your code to the following:

```
from some_file import country_to_continent_map

def get_continent(country):
    try:
        return country_to_continent_map[country]
    except KeyError:
        return 'Other'

col = 'Estimated HIV Prevalence% - (Ages 15-49)'

country = df[col]
country.apply(get_continent)
print(df.to_csv())
```

Comment: This still leaves me with the problem of unlabeled regions that are not countries such as states and cities. My current code is sufficient for returning the correct continent per country, my problem lies with non-country regions.

Comment: @LaurenA. sorry I misunderstood your problem.  Do you have the data for non-country regions?

Comment: It is included in the same column as the countries. The data is intertwined. I was asking to see if anybody knew of how to retrieve this information without just manually looking up each region the way I did for the countries. This is for a homework assgmt and I'm assuming there is an automated way that I just have not found as we were specifically asked not to manually input the information.